# MSIX in Docker container

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, msix

Does anyone know how to install an MSIX package into a Docker container?

Currently my Dockerfile does the following:

- Install PFX certificate to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities", which is specified by "Cert:\LocalMachine\Root" in the PowerShell command.
- Copy MSIX package from network drive.
- Install MSIX as an app. (Fails)
- Remove local copy of MSIX package.

Dockerfile:

```
RUN  powershell $pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'CeRtPaSsWoRd' -AsPlainText -Force; Import-PfxCertificate -Password $pwd -FilePath "R:/app-stream-cert.pfx" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root \
 && copy "R:/mcre-22-r2-x64.msix" "C:/" \
 && powershell Add-AppPackage -path "C:/mcre-22-r2-x64.msix" \
 && del "C:/mcre-22-r2-x64.msix"
```

I have this error:

```
Add-AppPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073D19, An error occurred
because a user was logged off.
error 0x80073D0A: Failed to install package
AnsysInc.mcre-22-r2_22.2.0.0_x64__13gfg92hgbc9g because the firewall service
is not running. Ensure that the firewall service is enabled and started.
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId]
b9bbd738-fed5-0000-fec9-bdb9d5fed801 in the Event Log or use the command line
Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID b9bbd738-fed5-0000-fec9-bdb9d5fed801
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AppPackage -path C:/mcre-22-r2-x64.msix
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (C:\mcre-22-r2-x64.msix:String) [A
   dd-AppxPackage], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageMa
   nager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
```

I've tried enabling firewall service in the container and on the host machine using `powershell Start-Service -Name mpssvc`. I'm able to enable firewall service on the host, but not in the container. Some posts indicate that Windows Docker containers share firewall service with their host. However my 0x80073D0A error still persists.

Environment info:

- Docker engine version 20.10.21
- Base image `mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2`
- Host OS Win 10 Pro 10.0.19044.2251

Comment: Looks like the workaround may be to (1) import the MSIX package to AdvancedInstaller18.4 (or similar), then (2) generate an MSI / EXE, and lastly (3) install the MSI / EXE in the container instead.